# Finer volume adjustment in iOS

Tags: iphone, itunes, audio, music, sound-volume

I use my iPhone to listen to music while I sleep. I usually gradually reduce the volume as I get more sleepy and sleepy, then I turn off the music by pressing the down volume key again when the volume is at the lowest quantized level, and I'm suddenly alert.

Is it possible to get fine volume adjustments on iPhone, similar to how it's possible on macOS?

What I've tried: I've tried lowering the volume of the music by manually editing it, but I don't have the time to edit all of my music that I choose from. (Plus, it doesn't work with Apple Music which I use - the files are DRM protected). I also tried leaving the volume slider "fullscreen" in Control Center and adjust it blindly, but it's really easy for me to touch elsewhere and exit the fullscreen.